# Specific detail of a Lebesgue integral with varying ranges of exponents.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

It was hard to come up with a good name for this post. Feel free to change it.

I am trying to solve the following problem, given to me by a fellow student, as we study for upcoming qualifying exams. No idea where he got it from:

---

"Determine the values of $p$ and $q$ for which the integral

$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{p-1}}{1+x^q}dx$$

exists as a Lebesgue integral. Hint: there should be a range of values."

---

Of course, "exists as a Lebesgue integral" really means "is finite".

I have observed the following:
When $p-1<0$, we have a problem as $x\to0$, similarly when $q<0$.

But I'm quite sure that simple inspection is not sufficient, and I have no idea how to prove that all other values work. I in fact doubt that I have found everything, and think that perhaps those ranges may be fine, since things like $\int_0^1\frac{x}{\ln x}dx$ exist as Lebesgue integrals, even though problems arise as $x\to 0$ at first glance.

Usually, when I prove a Lebesgue integral exists, I resort to sums, the integral test, monotone convergence theorem, etc., but I feel like that doesn't lead anywhere here, since the integrand may or may not be L-integrable.

This is precisely the type of problem I struggle with regularly. Also, be forewarned: I ask a lot of questions, usually. I will be back tomorrow morning to check in and see what I can learn. Many thanks for any and all help, y'all.

Comment: To start: Suppose $q>0.$ Then you can ignore the denominator near $0.$ We're led to this question: For which $p$ does $\int_0^1 x^{p-1}$ converge?

Comment: @zhw Yes, that part I can do, I think. Also, my integral goes to infinity, not $1$. But adjusting for that, I think a simple $p$-series/integral test works, and we get that $p<0$, right? But how to reconcile this further? How to consider the other cases? How to synthesize them?